# Laravel (cli) is using php 5.4 instead of 7

Tags: php, linux, laravel, centos7, plesk

When I run `php -v` it returns version `7.3.19`, `php` is an alias for `/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php`, the version of `/usr/bin/php` is `5.4.16`.

I've tried running Laravel like this: `/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/<the_domain>/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel new` inside the subdomain where I want Laravel but I still get the same errors: `Problem 1 - This package requires php ^7.2.5 but your PHP version (5.4.16) does not satisfy that requirement.`...

It's as if Laravel code is using the `/usr/bin/php` instead of `/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php` but I don't know how to solve that.

Edit: Composer had the same problem about php version being to low so I added the alias to .bash_profile which solved the issue but not for laravel.

Answer (score 0):

By default "`php`" command calls PHP version which is installed with operating system. The exact PHP binary called by php command is specified in operating system environment variables.

Read the document here to do an update.

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003766853-How-to-specify-command-line-command-php-version-for-SSH-user-on-the-Plesk-server-

Comment: I just wrote a comment but it disappeared for me so here it is again: I already did that for composer but I keep getting problems with laravel